# BufferedImage slows down performance

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm working on a game, nothing serious, just for fun. 
I wrote a class 'ImageBuilder' to help creating some images. 
Everything works fine, except one thing. 
I initialize a variabile like this:

```
// other stuff
m_tile = new ImageBuilder(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB).paint(0xff069dee).paintBorder(0xff4c4a4a, 1).build();
// other stuff
```

Then, in the rendering method, i have:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
         g.drawImage(m_tile, x * (TILE_SIZE + m_padding.x) + m_margin.x, y * (TILE_SIZE + m_padding.y) + m_margin.y, null);
    }
}
```

Note: m_padding and m_margin are just two Vector2i

This draws on the screen a simple 16x16 table using that image, but the game is almost frozen, i can't get more than like 10 FPS.

I tried to creating the image without that class, by doing this (TILE_SIZE = 32):

```
m_tile = new BufferedImage(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

for (int x = 0; x < TILE_SIZE; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < TILE_SIZE; y++) {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x + 1 == TILE_SIZE || y + 1 == TILE_SIZE)
             m_tile.setRGB(x, y, 0x4c4a4a);
        else
             m_tile.setRGB(x, y, 0x069dee);
    }
}
```

This time, i get 60 FPS.
I can't figure out with is the difference, i used to creating image using 'ImageBuilder' and all is fine, but not this time.

ImageBuilder class:

```
    // Constructor
    public ImageBuilder(int width, int height, int imageType) {
        this.m_width = width;
        this.m_height = height;
        this.m_image = new BufferedImage(m_width, m_height, imageType);
        this.m_pixels = ((DataBufferInt) m_image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        this.m_image_type = imageType;
    }

    public ImageBuilder paint(int color) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_pixels.length; i++) m_pixels[i] = color;
        return this;
    }

    public ImageBuilder paintBorder(int color, int stroke) {
        for (int x = 0; x < m_width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < m_height; y++) {
                if (x < stroke || y < stroke || x + stroke >= m_width || y + stroke >= m_height) {
                    m_pixels[x + y * m_width] = color;
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BufferedImage build() {
        return m_image;
    }
```

There are other methods, but i don't call them, so i don't think is necessary to write them

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: If your tiles use a different ColorModel than your destination, that would slow down the drawing significantly.  If you’re drawing to a Graphics of a component, create your tile images by calling [createCompatibleImage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#createCompatibleImage(int,int,int)) on [that component’s GraphicsConfiguration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphicsConfiguration()).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is your `ImageBuilder` accessing the backing data array of the data buffer:

```
this.m_pixels = ((DataBufferInt) m_image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Doing so, may (will) ruin the chances for this image being hardware accelerated. This is documented behaviour, from the [`getData()` API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBufferInt.html#getData()):

> Note that calling this method may cause this `DataBuffer` object to be incompatible with performance optimizations used by some implementations (such as caching an associated image in video memory).

You could probably get around this easily, by using a temporary image in your bilder, and returning a copy of the temp image from the `build()` method, that has not been "tampered" with.

For best performance, always using a compatible image (as in `createCompatibleImage()`, mentioned by @VGR in the comments) is a good idea too. This should ensure you have the fastest possible hardware blits.

Comment: I just changed build() making it returns a copy of the image and now works great, thank you